ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
I am trying to use the project of UncleRus on Github : text . I want to build the hx711 project example. I am using correct versions of Cmaker (3.5), and VisualStudioCode.
However, even after considering the Github readme instructions, I am facing a problem that I can't find a way to solve. Here are the logs :
C:\Users\CorentinLEROY\eesp\esp-idf-lib\examples\hx711>idf.py build
Executing action: all (aliases: build)
Running ninja in directory C:\Users\CorentinLEROY\eesp\esp-idf-lib\examples\hx711\build
Executing "ninja all"...
[0/1] Re-running CMake...-- ccache will be used for faster recompilation
-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32
CMake Error at C:/Users/CorentinLEROY/esp/v5.0.6/esp-idf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:245 (message):
  Failed to resolve component 'driver'.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/CorentinLEROY/esp/v5.0.6/esp-idf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:281 (__build_resolve_and_add_req)
  C:/Users/CorentinLEROY/esp/v5.0.6/esp-idf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:282 (__build_expand_requirements)
  C:/Users/CorentinLEROY/esp/v5.0.6/esp-idf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:574 (__build_expand_requirements)
  C:/Users/CorentinLEROY/esp/v5.0.6/esp-idf/tools/cmake/project.cmake:530 (idf_build_process)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/CorentinLEROY/eesp/esp-idf-lib/examples/hx711/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
FAILED: build.ninja
C:\Users\CorentinLEROY\.espressif\tools\cmake\3.24.0\bin\cmake.exe --regenerate-during-build -SC:\Users\CorentinLEROY\eesp\esp-idf-lib\examples\hx711 -BC:\Users\CorentinLEROY\eesp\esp-idf-lib\examples\hx711\build
ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
HINT: The component driver could not be found. This could be because: component name was misspelled, the component was not added to the build, the component has been moved to the IDF component manager or has been removed and refactored into some other component.
Please look out for component in 'https://components.espressif.com' and add using 'idf.py add-dependency' command.
Refer to the migration guide for more details about moved components.
Refer to the build-system guide for more details about how components are found and included in the build.
ninja failed with exit code 1, output of the command is in the C:\Users\CorentinLEROY\eesp\esp-idf-lib\examples\hx711\build\log\idf_py_stderr_output_19500 and C:\Users\CorentinLEROY\eesp\esp-idf-lib\examples\hx711\build\log\idf_py_stdout_output_19500

I tried to modify the path of the components folder in my esp-idf folder in the cmake file :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(COMPONENT_DIRS ${EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS} C:/Users/CorentinLEROY/eesp/esp-idf-lib/components)


include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(example-hx711)


Nothing changed. So I decided to create a new project from the example one but again, nothing happend. I checked the several files from the hx711 component folder and hx711.c and hx711.h are here.

Read carefuly your log. You seem to need a component called driver. The hint tells you what to do or where to get it. I guess you need to follow the link and try to rebuid.

I have already checked this link and try adding a component like an I2C component to control I2C devices. I a not sure of what kind of component is missing. I also checked on the github and I can't find a file "idf_component.yml" which is the file where I should see the component. I have my idf_component.yml on my /project/hx711/main. I tried several components that could be useful but there is still the same message.

I found the issue, I was about a version of the dependencies that was not stable enough!
